# Magento 2.4.3-p1 production mode not working

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.4

I am using Magento 2.4.3-p1, on windows.
Have created a custom theme by extending the luma theme.
In development mode, my side is working pretty much fine,

> *except for product images not showing on the home page, when calling via blocks.*

**Second:**

When I am setting to production mode, the following happens (Note: I am using page builder to create pages)

1. Category menu is not getting displayed
2. None of images getting displayed – images used in block, slider

Surprisingly, product images start rendering fine, which was not working in developer mode.

I ran following commands,

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento se:s:d –f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Unable to solve the problem. Can anyone point out what wrong I doing?

Thanks,